# how to open user control page in popup using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to open user control page in popup window. show popup during page load.

below is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        title: "jQuery Dialog Popup",
        buttons: {
            Close: function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

below is the user control page code:

```
<div id="dialog" style="display: none;position:fixed; margin: 0 0 0 570px;width:50%; height:10%;">         
    <uc3:ucPageUsage ID="ucPageUSage1" runat="server"/> 
</div>
```

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function ShowComment(val) {

    document.getElementById('ucPageUSage1_hdn_rdo').value = val.value;

    document.getElementById('ucPageUSage1_btn').click();


}
function HidePage() {
    document.getElementById('ucPageUSage1_div_page').style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
<div id="div_page" runat="server" style="border-bottom-style:ridge; background-    color:White;" visible="true">
<table id="PUTable" align="center" runat="server"  width="100%" cellpadding="4"  cellspacing="4" border="0">
<tr>
<td class="style1" valign="top">
<div id="divrate" runat="server">
<b>Did this Page help you?</b>
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdoRate" CssClass="PUText" runat="server" RepeatDirection ="Vertical" >
<asp:ListItem Value="1" onClick="javascript:ShowComment(this); ">Yes</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="2" onClick="javascript:ShowComment(this); ">No</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="3" onClick="javascript:ShowComment(this); ">Not very  useful</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>

<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" CssClass="hiddenbutton" OnClick="btn_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
</div>
<asp:Label ID="lblInfo" runat="server" Visible="false" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>

<div id="divcom" runat="server" visible="false">

<asp:TextBox ID="txtComment" CssClass="PUText" ForeColor="Black" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" 
    Width="256px" Height="35px"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
<br />
</div>        
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdn_rdo" runat="server" />
</div>
```

when i run this page, user control page displayed separatly instead of displaying inside popup window.

i want to show usercontrol page inside popup window.

Comment: Please post RENDERED HTML too. A jsfiddle.net as well would be great

Comment: sorry. what does rendered html mean?

Comment: Actual HTML as in view-source instead of `<uc3.../>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The css style is moving the contents out of the Popup window, I would suggest the remove the css style and try, like below.

```
<div id="dialog">         
    <uc3:ucPageUsage ID="ucPageUSage1" runat="server"/> 
</div>
```

Comment: yes thanks. now it comes inside popup. but control in user control page is not working. I'm having radio button and submit button in user control page. I cant able to submit.

Comment: you will have have to set UseSubmitBehavior="false" for the button. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729306/cannot-click-on-an-asp-net-button-within-a-jquery-dialog) for more details.

Comment: It seems it will not work with ImageButton. Few solutions are [suggested here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1153174.aspx?Image+button+with+use+submit+behavior+false), you may have to wrap your button(imageButton) within a table.

Comment: In my user control page, i cant get my values of asp controls. Am using radiobuttonlist and textbox. when i click submit their values are null. dont know what s wrong in my code.In question pls refer third code.

Comment: can any1 help me 2 find the cause?